# Jenkins Multiple Projects Same Workspace

Tags: jenkins

I thought this was easy until I had an error running it for the workspace already existing. I have a selenium automation suite and it is running specrun. I have it currently running a full @regression tag. I want to clone the project so I can run an @smoke tag. This is identical source control but I just want it to run smoke or regression. In an effort to save some space, I was hoping to use the same workspace.

How is the best way to go about resolving this?

Comment: "until I had an error running it for the workspace already existing" - can you please elaborate the error you received and how you implemented it?

Comment: Hey Dvir669 - I cloned the projects in Jenkins and changed the project names to be *-Smoke. Everything else I left the same other than changing the tag in the command line test run. When I ran it I had errors because it said work space already existed. That was my whole point lol. I was just trying to conserve some disk space. I have everything running but it just seemed like this was not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about Automation testing but I have used Jenkins so as per my opinion, one way is you should **make sub-projects** under one Project which will let you use same workspace.

Other way is to use **This build is parameterized** under **job configuration**, in that option you can passed your different commands.(For more detail feel free to ask me)

There are other ways to do the same but for that I need some information.

As you said you have "cloned the projects in Jenkins and changed the project names", so ***to remove your error which is (workspace already existed)*** please check your 
**job configuration** ==> **Advanced Project Options** ==> **Use custom workspace**

If **Use custom workspace** is checked, then check **Directory** field is set to the **same directory**  for your **cloned jobs**.

***Solution*** :- There are two options

1. Uncheck the **Use custom workspace** option
2. Give **different directories** for each job.